# HTML Traverse and Find Best Practices

Tags: find, traversal

Hey I was thinking about making some crawlers so that I can get an URL and traverse through the html and just get certain things I might need/want. I was thinking about using Php + xPath but I'm not sure that might be the best way. What do you guys think? Are there any best practices, recommendations, or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I had some good results reusing the Parse class from Fit/Fitnesse for getting data out of html tables.